# Jquery - Dynamic Input Box along with add/ remove button in every row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

JQuery based UI where user can add Input Boxes dynamically. It should look as follows.

Default look:

- INPUT_BOX   [ADD_BUTTON]   [REMOVE_BUTTON]

Click on the [Add_Button] add another row as follows and so on

- INPUT_BOX   [DISABLED_ADD_BUTTON]   [REMOVE_BUTTON]
- INPUT_BOX   [DISABLED_ADD_BUTTON]   [REMOVE_BUTTON]
- INPUT_BOX   [DISABLED_ADD_BUTTON]   [REMOVE_BUTTON]
- INPUT_BOX   [ADD_BUTTON]   [REMOVE_BUTTON]

Following approach creates the similar one, but newly added add buttons are not working. Only the top row Add button works

```
     var x = 1; //initial text box count
     $(".add_field_button").click(function(e){ //on add input button click
                  e.preventDefault();
                  if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                      x++; //text box increment
                      $("#input_fields_wrap").append('<div style="padding-top:4px">\n<label></label>\n<input name="key_'+ x +'" class="key-value">\n<input name="value_'+ x +'" class="key-value">\n<button class="add_field_button" name="add" type="button">Add</button>\n<button name="remove" class="remove_field" type="button">Remove</button>\n</div>'); 
                  }
 });

   $("#input_fields_wrap").on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
                  e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
});
```

HTML Snippet used:

```
        <div id="input_fields_wrap">
          <div>
            <label>Properties</label>
            <input class="key-value" name="key_0" />
            <input class="key-value" name="value_0" />
            <button type="button" name="add" class="add_field_button">Add</button>
            <button type="button" class="remove_field" name="remove">Remove</button>
           </div>
        </div>
```

My requirement is every row Add button and remove buttons active. Looking for help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `event delegation` for add button also,

```
$("#input_fields_wrap").on("click", ".add_field_button", function(e) {
```

The first add button will work, because it will be available in the DOM when you registering event for it. But the buttons which will be added in a later time cannot be matched during event hook up.